# Symfony form eventlistener string error

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony, symfony-3.1

Entity\Profile.php

```
class Profile
{
    ...
    /**
    * @var string
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
    */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="province", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $province;
    ...
}
```

MyProfileTypeForm.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    ...
    ->add('country', CountryType::class, array(
        'label' => 'form.profile.country',
        'preferred_choices' => array(
            'US'
        )
    ))
    ...

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $country = $form->get('country')->getData();

        $form->add('province', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'UserBundle:LocationProvince',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'choice_value' => 'id',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($country) {
                return $er
                    ->createQueryBuilder('l')
                    ->where('l.countryCode = :cc')
                    ->setParameter(':cc', $country);
            },
            'label' => 'form.profile.province',
        ));
    });
}
```

Error Code:

An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE profile SET province = ? WHERE id = ?' with params [{}, 1]:

Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Panel\UserBundle\Entity\LocationProvince could not be converted to string

Description:

The Entity of getting the country code. Provincial list drawn by the country code. But it does not record.

Answer (score 0):

in your province choice drop-down list you've specified:

```
'choice_value' => 'id',
```

But I believe "id" is an integer.
You probably need to change this to:

```
'choice_value' => 'province',
```

Try that - I think it should work.